# Calling 'myModel.predict' in graph mode is not supported

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras

> Had some issues on this when developing image recognition website

```
[2021-07-19 02:27:21,880] ERROR in app: Exception on /uploads/comedy3.jpg [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ram Raj\anaconda3\envs\Tutorial\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Ram Raj\anaconda3\envs\Tutorial\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Ram Raj\anaconda3\envs\Tutorial\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Ram Raj\anaconda3\envs\Tutorial\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Ram Raj\anaconda3\envs\Tutorial\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Ram Raj\anaconda3\envs\Tutorial\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Ram Raj\Desktop\Ai project\website.py", line 83, in uploaded_file
    result = myModel.predict(test_image)
  File "C:\Users\Ram Raj\anaconda3\envs\Tutorial\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1671, in predict
    version_utils.disallow_legacy_graph('Model', 'predict')
  File "C:\Users\Ram Raj\anaconda3\envs\Tutorial\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\version_utils.py", line 130, in disallow_legacy_graph
    raise ValueError(error_msg)
ValueError: Calling `Model.predict` in graph mode is not supported when the `Model` instance was constructed with eager mode enabled. Please construct your `Model` instance in graph mode or call `Model.predict` with eager mode enabled.
```

> Here is the code

```
from flask import render_template
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from keras.backend import set_session
import tensorflow as tf

app = Flask(__name__)

def load_model_from_file():
    mySession = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    set_session(mySession)
    myModel = load_model('saved_model.h5')
    myGraph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
    return (mySession, myModel, myGraph)
```

> I have just showed part where it shows wrong only. Hope able to understand it

```
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    test_image = image.load_img(UPLOAD_FOLDER+"/"+filename, target_size =(150,150))
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)

    mySession = app.config['SESSION']
    myModel = app.config['MODEL']
    myGraph = app.config['GRAPH']
    with myGraph.as_default():
        set_session(mySession)
        result = myModel.predict(test_image)
        image_src = "/"+UPLOAD_FOLDER +"/"+filename
        if result[0] < 0.5 :
            answer = "<div class='col text-center'><img width='150' height='150' src='"+image_src+"' class='img-thumbnail' /><h4>guess:"+x+" "+str(result[0])+"</h4></div><div class='col'></div><div class='w-100'></div>"     
        else:
            answer = "<div class='col'></div><div class='col text-center'><img width='150' height='150' src='"+image_src+"' class='img-thumbnail' /><h4>guess:"+y+" "+str(result[0])+"</h4></div><div class='w-100'></div>"     
        results.append(answer)
        return render_template('index.html',myX=x,myY=y,mySampleX=samplex,mySampleY=sampley,len=len(results),results=results)



def main():
    (mySession, myModel, myGraph) = load_model_from_file()
    
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super secret key'
    app.config['SESSION'] = mySession
    app.config['MODEL'] = myModel
    app.config['GRAPH'] = myGraph
    
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
    app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
    app.run()


results = []

main()
```

> Any idea on where is the fault that i did ? As i couldn't understand much when i searched it at tensorflow website as well. The version that i'm using was 2.5.0
> thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

> ValueError: Calling `Model.predict` in graph mode is not supported
> when the `Model` instance was constructed with eager mode enabled.
> `Please construct your Model instance in graph mode or call Model.predict` with eager mode enabled.

As error says load the model graph mode and call the Model.predict function.

Load your model inside the graph as shown below:

```
with graph.as_default():
    #Load your model
    #call model.predict
    Model.predict()
    return
```